# Gradle cucumber error in command-line - command 'C:\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, cucumber-java

When I run cucumber test from IntelliJ terminal commandline and get subject error:

Version:

```
λ java --version
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)


λ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17 (Oracle Corporation 17+35-LTS-2724)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

However I have below code in my build.gradle file

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = 'Run integration tests.'
    check.dependsOn(it)
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    // Prints any test outcomes to the console
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        showStackTraces true
        showExceptions true
        showCauses true
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output

    }
}

configurations {

    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }

    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly

}

    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    java.targetCompatibility = java.sourceCompatibility
    
    task cucumber() {
        dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    
        doLast {
            javaexec {    <============  Line 279 ===========
                main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
                classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
                args = ['--plugin', 'pretty',
                        '--plugin', 'html:target/cucumber-report.html',
                        '--glue', 'xxxxx.stepdefinitions',
                        'src/integrationTest/resources']
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what is missing. However cucumber tests are running via IntelliJ IDE edit configuration without any issue.

This is stacktrace error:

```
λ gradlew cucumber                                                                                                                                            
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :cucumber FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\xxxxx\build.gradle' line: 279  <==========

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
....
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly tells the reasons:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

For some reason, the Java executable fails to launch the process on your system. The common problem could be with the antivirus/firewall blocking the process. Make sure to exclude the JDK directory from the scan.

Comment: I have already disabled firewall/antivirus. Is there other way to get more specific details? Other point is I have Spring-boot prjects with Maven where tests run smoothly in commandline.

Comment: As per the error log in the question  `line: 279  <==========` this is must be just specific to `javaexec` in that gradle `cucumber()` task.

Comment: Further, just to make sure it is my local java version or something else, I ran tests in Jenkins. Noticed same error in Jenkins as well. Therefore this is something to do with cucumber() task. However in Cucumber docs has the same code (step 5)  https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/java/#gradle